# uncheck check box if clicked anywhere from the webpage using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to know how to uncheck all checked check-box when I click anywhere in the page.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mychecked[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mychecked[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mychecked[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="mychecked[]"/>

<div id="count"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var msg = "checked " +$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length +" items";
    $('#count').html(msg);
});
```

here is a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xzL4a/15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var msg = "checked " + $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length + " items";
    $('#count').html(msg);
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/xa9xzL4a/16/)

Or use **[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

    if (!$(e.target).is($('input[type="checkbox"]'))) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
    } else {
        var msg = "checked " + $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length + " items";
        $('#count').html(msg);

    }
});
```

Comment: how can I do this using .not()?

Comment: @AnthonyLloveras see updated code, that will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this : add click event for document and clear all checkboxes if clicked element is not a checkbox

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var msg = "checked " +$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length +" items";
    $('#count').html(msg);
});
$(document).on('click',function(e){
  //check if clicked element is not checkbox
 if(e.target.type!="checkbox")
 {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false); 
    $('#count').html("");
 }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xa9xzL4a/24/)**